# To connect to cassandra with jdbc with ssl validation disabled

Tags: cassandra

I am using simba cassandra jdbc driver to connect to cassandra. My jdbc url is: `jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9042?ssl=true`. How to disable the ssl validation, like in postgress we can do `sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` . I am looking for similar thing for cassandra. Any pointers would help

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc42</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jar/CassandraJDBC42.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: JDBC isn't the best way to access Cassandra. It's better to use DataStax Java driver for that

Comment: Can I know why isnt the best way?

Comment: because JDBC driver may not take into account things like load balancing, etc.

Comment: It’s for testing . Not for production code. So jdbc should be okay I guess